# shortest command to print a to z one per line in bash

Tags: linux, bash

Is there anything shorter than this ?

```bash
for k in {a..z}; do echo $k; done
```

I am writing some notes (educational purpose) on how to use the awk command and this will be piped to it.

Comment: The last paragraph seems to belong to a totally different question, or else you need to explain in more detail how it is at all related to what you are asking here.

Comment: Simpler is just `echo -e {a..z}"\n"`

Comment: ... though `echo -e` has some pesky portability issues.

Comment: @stark Nice. Or `echo -e "\n"{a..z}` to avoid the leading spaces (but not the empty first line).

Comment: For a teaching document, use [triplee's `printf`.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76180947/8656552).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is definitely shorter;

```
printf '%s\n' {a..z}
```

Comment: And `print -l {a..z}` if golfing with zsh instead of bash.

Comment: If *golfing*, `printf %s\\n {a..z}` in `bash` drops another character. :)

Answer (score 4):

```
jot -c 26 97
```

---

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
i
j
k
l
m
n
o
p
q
r
s
t
u
v
w
x
y
z
```

Comment: 12 chars. is shortest so far.

Comment: However, `jot` is not a standard utility. It is included in BSD-based distros, but commonly not on Linux.

Comment: @tripleee : that's true, and portability wasn't one of the requested criteria. `Linux` distros also tend to only include `gnu-cut`, which can't even properly substring `UTF-8` input, so there's that (which is even more ironic considering that `gnu-wc` handles `UTF-8` just fine, but apparently those 2 aren't even in sync)

Comment: The question is tagged [tag:linux] though of course, that could mean many things.

Comment: @tripleee : OP also said he's writing notes about `awk` yet didn't tag `awk` so there's that

Answer (score 3):

This is also shorter:

```bash
echo {a..z} | tr ' ' '\n'
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be aware of this.

```
12:00 boffi:~ $ for a in {a..d} ; do echo $a | awk '{print NR $1}' ; done
1a
1b
1c
1d
12:00 boffi:~ $ printf '%s\n'  {a..d} | awk '{print NR $1}'
1a
2b
3c
4d
12:01 boffi:~ $ for a in {a..d} ; do echo $a ; done | awk '{print NR $1}'
1a
2b
3c
4d
```

Depending on what you want to demonstrate with `awk`, [the answer you've received](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76180947/2749397) could be what you want or simply what you've asked for.